# Part of the char array?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, char

I got a task in which I receive babies' firstname and weight in kilogram in a character array (for example: Johnny, 2 kg). I must store them in an array that can hold maximum 1000 elements and must be a struct type, storing the baby's firstname and weight.

Every actions must be done in functions - however, when I tried to get the name until the comma, str.copy() didn't work for me. Its specific problem was something with the last parameter, the position. Could someone help me out with that? Also, I'm kinda new to C++ and imagining how to separately, in two functions ask in the char arrays until empty line and do the copying in the other... if someone could help me out, I'd be grateful for that ^^'

Thanks for the help in advance!

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#define M 1000

struct baby{
    std::string baby_name;
    float weight;
    
};

int readIn(baby* baby_datapair, int max);
// int maxWeight(baby* baby_datapair);
// int minWeight(baby* baby_datapair);
// void descendingOrder(baby* baby_datapair, int num);

int main(){
    
    baby baby_array[M];
    int n = readIn(baby_array, M);
    
    
    return 0;
}

int readIn(baby* baby_datapair, int max){
    
    int n = 0;
    char name[12];
    while (n < max){
        std::cout << "Baby" << n+1 << "'s datas (Nickname, weight in kg): ";
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
        //~ std::cin.ignore(1);
        if (neve == ""){
            std::cout << "Wrong input!\n";
            break;
        }else{
            std::size_t pos = name.find(',');
            std::size_t until = name.copy(baby_datapair[n].baby_name, 0, pos);
            
        }
        n++;

    }
        
    return n;
}

// int maxWeight(baby* baby_datapair){
    
// }

// int minWeight(baby* baby_datapair){
    
// }

// void descendingOrder(baby* baby_datapair, int num){
    
    
// }
```

Comment: Please make a *minimally reproducible example*. It's good to have both though, first some background about where the problem originates, and then a minimally reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `std::string name;` instead of `char name[12];` as std::getline 's parameter. BTW, It make better for memory management. After input data, check pos value for valid value.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

#define M 1000

struct baby {
    std::string baby_name;
    float weight;

};

int readIn(baby* baby_datapair, int max);
// int maxWeight(baby* baby_datapair);
// int minWeight(baby* baby_datapair);
// void descendingOrder(baby* baby_datapair, int num);

int main() {

    baby baby_array[M];
    int n = readIn(baby_array, M);


    return 0;
}

int readIn(baby* baby_datapair, int max) {

    int n = 0;
    //char name[12];
    std::string name;
    while (n < max) {
        std::cout << "Baby" << n + 1 << "'s datas (Nickname, weight in kg): ";
        std::getline(std::cin, name);
        //~ std::cin.ignore(1);
        if (name == "") {
            std::cout << "Wrong input!\n";
            break;
        }
        else {
            std::size_t pos = name.find(',');
            if (pos <= 0) {
                std::cout << "Invalid input structure!\n";
                continue;
            }
            //std::size_t until = name.copy(baby_datapair[n].baby_name, 0, pos);
            baby_datapair[n].baby_name = name.substr(0, pos);
            baby_datapair[n].weight =(float)atof(name.substr(pos+1).c_str());

            //std::cout << std::endl;
            //std::cout << baby_datapair[n].baby_name;
            //std::cout << ", " << baby_datapair[n].weight;
        }
        n++;

    }

    return n;
}

// int maxWeight(baby* baby_datapair){

// }

// int minWeight(baby* baby_datapair){

// }

// void descendingOrder(baby* baby_datapair, int num){


// }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking it the wrong size. You should not try to copy to, but just copy from. BTW, `name` must be a `std::string` for you program to compile, and you should check for possible end of file. So a minally fixed version could be:

```
std::string name;
while (n < max) {
    std::cout << "Baby" << n + 1 << "'s datas (Nickname, weight in kg): ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    //~ std::cin.ignore(1);
    if ((! std::cin) || name == "") {
        std::cout << "Wrong input!\n";
        break;
    }
    else {
        std::size_t pos = name.find(',');
        baby_datapair[n].baby_name = std::string(name.c_str(), pos);
        baby_datapair[n].weight = strtof(name.c_str() + pos + 1, nullptr);

    }
```

But using a `std::stringstream` would be more idiomatic in C++. Above code is rather C-ish...